# Customizing kubernetes dashboard with company name and environment

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

**Problem statement:**
Currently we are running k8s in multiple environments e.g. dev, uat,staging.
It becomes very difficult to identify for us just by looking at k8s dashboard UI.
Do we have any facility to customize k8s dashboard indicating somewhere in header or footer cluster or environment we are using?

Comment: its open source, you can modify it

Answer (score 2):

Since K8S is open source, you should have the ability to do whatever you want. You will ofcourse need to play with the code and build you own custom dashboard image.

You can start off from here

> https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/tree/master/src/app/frontend

Answer (score 0):

[This feature](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/2239) was released back in 2017, with [the introduction of the settings ConfigMap](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/2417). You just need to set the values of the kubernetes-dashboard-settings ConfigMap in kubernetes-dashboard namespace. You don't even need to restart the dashboard service/deployment.